# How to read List<Model class> in Nested structures with Lists?

Tags: dart, flutter

How to get one by one values in Nested structures with Lists json structure.

**controller.dart**

```
 final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    AssetRegister model = AssetRegister.fromJson(jsonResponse);
    print(model.data);
```

> how to print like this print(model.dart.i);//error

**model.dart**

```
class AssetRegister {
  final List<Data> data;

  AssetRegister({this.data});

  factory AssetRegister.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var list = json['data'] as List;
    print(list.runtimeType);
    List<Data> assetList = list.map((i) => Data.fromJson(i)).toList();

    return AssetRegister(data: assetList);
  }
}

class Data {
  final int i;
  final String d;

  Data({this.i, this.d});

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Data(
      i: json['i'],
      d: json['d'],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide toString method implementation for Data class like this:

```
class Data {
    final int i;
    final String d;

    Data({this.i, this.d});

    factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return Data(
            i: json['i'],
            d: json['d'],
        );
    }

  @override
  String toString() => return 'i = $i, $d';
}
```